# SQL TOP 10 Ranking Query Help Required

Tags: sql, ms-access, ranking

I have the code below and I am trying to find out the top 10 servers used in the last month, but having issues, not very good with SQL. Need some help or advice if possible.

I got this working on top 10 Apps but cannot figure out how to make this happen for top 10 servers.

```
SELECT TOP 10 dbo_LU_SERVERNAME.SERVERNAME, Count(*) AS SessionNumbers
FROM dbo_LU_SERVERNAME INNER JOIN dbo_SDB_SESSION ON dbo_LU_SERVERNAME.PK_SERVERNAMEID = dbo_SDB_SESSION.FK_SERVERNAMEID
WHERE (((dbo_SDB_SESSION.SESSIONSTART) Between Now() And DateAdd("d",-30,Now())))
GROUP BY dbo_LU_SERVERNAME.SERVERNAME
ORDER BY Count(*) DESC;

UNION ALL SELECT "Other" AS SERVERNAME, Count(*) AS SessionNumbers
FROM (dbo_LU_SERVERNAME
INNER JOIN dbo_SDB_SESSION  
ON dbo_LU_SERVER.PK_SERVERID = dbo_SDB_SESSION.FK_SERVERID)  
LEFT JOIN (SELECT TOP 10 dbo_LU_SERVERNAME.SERVERNAME, Count(*) AS SessionNos 
           FROM dbo_LU_SERVERNAME
           INNER JOIN dbo_SDB_SESSION 
           ON dbo_LU_SERVER.PK_SERVERID = dbo_SDB_SESSION.FK_SERVERID
           WHERE (((dbo_SDB_SESSION.SESSIONSTART) Between Now() And DateAdd("d",-31,Now())))
           GROUP BY dbo_LU_SERVERNAME.SERVERNAME
           ORDER BY Count(*) DESC) AS s  ON dbo_LU_SERVERNAME.SERVERNAME = s.SERVERNAME

WHERE s.SERVERNAME Is Null
GROUP BY "Other";
```

This is the SQL that is working for top 10 APPS.

```
SELECT TOP 10 dbo_LU_APPNAME.APPNAME, Count(*) AS SessionNos
FROM dbo_LU_APPNAME INNER JOIN dbo_SDB_SESSION ON dbo_LU_APPNAME.PK_APPNAMEID = dbo_SDB_SESSION.FK_APPNAMEID
WHERE (((dbo_SDB_SESSION.SESSIONSTART) Between Now() And DateAdd("d",-30,Now())))
GROUP BY dbo_LU_APPNAME.APPNAME
ORDER BY Count(*) DESC;

UNION ALL SELECT "Other" AS APPNAME, Count(*) AS SessionNos 
FROM (dbo_LU_APPNAME
INNER JOIN dbo_SDB_SESSION  
ON dbo_LU_APPNAME.PK_APPNAMEID = dbo_SDB_SESSION.FK_APPNAMEID)  
LEFT JOIN (SELECT TOP 10 dbo_LU_APPNAME.APPNAME, Count(*) AS SessionNos 
           FROM dbo_LU_APPNAME
           INNER JOIN dbo_SDB_SESSION 
           ON dbo_LU_APPNAME.PK_APPNAMEID = dbo_SDB_SESSION.FK_APPNAMEID
           WHERE (((dbo_SDB_SESSION.SESSIONSTART) Between Now() And DateAdd("d",-31,Now())))
           GROUP BY dbo_LU_APPNAME.APPNAME
           ORDER BY Count(*) DESC) AS s  ON dbo_LU_APPNAME.APPNAME = s.APPNAME

WHERE s.APPNAME Is Null
GROUP BY "Other";
```

---

**Please note that the tables are related as:**
dbo_LU_SERVER ---> FK_SERVERNAMEID, PK_SERVERID
dbo_LU_SERVERNAME ---> PK_SERVERNAMEID
dbo.SDB.SESSION ---> FK_SERVERID

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Please Help.

Thank you

Comment: What you don't explain in your question is the use of the UNION ALL. I'm gussing it's a total count of all server sessions not included in the top 10 list. Therefore your final list will be 11 rows, the top 10 servers and then a count of all the other sessions.

Comment: You have tagged your question with SQL and ms-access and visual-basic. I'm assuming you are writing this query for Access but where does the VB part come in?

Comment: This is from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205902/need-help-with-sql-query-in-access/2206029#2206029 is it not?

Comment: Yes, looks the same. Perhaps this question should be closed.

Comment: I imagine the problem is the addition of the date, so Other is including everything, regardless of date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to answer my question.

```
SELECT TOP 10 dbo_LU_SERVERNAME.SERVERNAME, Count(*) AS SessionNumbers
FROM dbo_LU_SERVERNAME INNER JOIN dbo_SDB_SESSION ON dbo_LU_SERVERNAME.PK_SERVERNAMEID = dbo_SDB_SESSION.FK_SERVERID
WHERE (((dbo_SDB_SESSION.SESSIONSTART) Between Now() And DateAdd("d",-30,Now())))
GROUP BY dbo_LU_SERVERNAME.SERVERNAME
ORDER BY Count(*) DESC;

UNION ALL SELECT "Other" AS SERVERNAME, Count(*) AS SessionNumbers
FROM  (dbo_LU_SERVERNAME INNER JOIN dbo_SDB_SESSION ON dbo_LU_SERVERNAME.PK_SERVERNAMEID = dbo_SDB_SESSION.FK_SERVERID)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT TOP 10 dbo_LU_SERVERNAME.SERVERNAME, Count(*) AS SessionNos 
           FROM dbo_LU_SERVERNAME INNER JOIN dbo_SDB_SESSION ON dbo_LU_SERVERNAME.PK_SERVERNAMEID = dbo_SDB_SESSION.FK_SERVERID
           WHERE (((dbo_SDB_SESSION.SESSIONSTART) Between Now() And DateAdd("d",-31,Now())))
           GROUP BY dbo_LU_SERVERNAME.SERVERNAME
           ORDER BY Count(*) DESC) AS a  ON dbo_LU_SERVERNAME.SERVERNAME = a.SERVERNAME

WHERE a.SERVERNAME Is Null
GROUP BY "Other";
```

Thanks for your comments, I did ask another question some time before almost the same as this but the other one is regarding two related entities, this is three related entities.

Thanks again

Cheers :)